# Prove that the set $\{f\in \mathfrak G|f(p)=w\}$(where $w$ is a $r$th root of unity) is a coset of the subgroup $\{f\in \mathfrak G|f(p)=1\}$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, characteristic-functions, dirichlet-series

Consider the group of units of integer modulo $k$ that is $\Bbb Z_k^*$. There consider the character as a map  $f:\Bbb N \to \Bbb C$ s.t $f(n) =
\begin{cases}
f(\bar n)  & \text{if $(n,k)=1$ } \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

So the character is a group homomorphism on $\Bbb Z_k^*$.

Now consider the character group $\mathfrak G$. My question is:

**

> Let $\bar p$ has order $r$ in $\Bbb Z_k^*$. Then the values of $f(p)$
>   are the $r$th root of unity.
>
> Prove that the set $\{f\in \mathfrak G|f(p)=w\}$(where $w$ is a $r$th root of unity) is a coset of the subgroup $\{f\in \mathfrak G|f(p)=1\}$.

**

I was studying John Binder's notes to prove Dirichlet's Theorem.

There it is written at page 14 [Analytic Number Theory and Dirichlet's Theorem](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Binder.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism, and $b\in\text{Im}\, f$,
then $f^{-1}(b)=\{a\in G:f(a)=b\}$ is a coset (left or right) of $K=\text{Ker}\, f$. This is because, if $a_0\in f^{-1}(b)$ then
$a\in f^{-1}(b)$ iff $f(a)=f(a_0)$ iff $aa_0^{-1}\in K$ iff $a\in Ka_0 $.