# Show that the set of some rotations $S_v$ is a coset of $H_v=\{T\in G:Tv=v\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, linear-transformations

I am stuck while solving the following problem:

> **Problem** (Source: [University of California, Berkeley - Prelim exams](https://math.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/pages/Fall80.pdf))
>
> Let $G$ be the group of orthogonal transformations of $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ with determinant $1$. Let $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$, $|v|=1$, and let $H_v=\{T\in G\mid Tv=v\}$.
>
> (a) Show that $H_v$ is a subgroup of $G$.
>
> (b) Let $S_v=\{T\in G\mid T\text{ is a rotation through $180^\circ$ about a line orthogonal to $v$}\}$. Show that $S_v$ is a coset of $H_v$ in $G$.

I easily solved step (a), so I know that $H_v$ is a subgroup of $G$. If I find a matrix $A\in G$ such that $S_v=AH_v$, then I succeed to show that $S_v$ is a coset of $H_v$ in $G$. However, I don't know how to find $A$.

**My notes:**

1. Take $T\in S_v$, then $T^2$ is a rotation through $360^\circ$ about a line, so $T^2$ is the identity. Especially, $Tv=-v$. Thus $T$ have an eigenvalue $-1$ associated with $v$, while elements in $H_v$ have an eigenvalue $1$ associated with $v$.
2. In the post [Prove that the set $\{f\in \mathfrak G|f(p)=w\}$(where $w$ is a $r$th root of unity) is a coset of the subgroup $\{f\in \mathfrak G|f(p)=1\}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349222/310026), I got the statement that if $f$ is a group homomorphism and $b\in \operatorname{Im}f$, then $f^{-1}(b)$ is a coset of $\ker f$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint, since you say you don't know how to find $A$: $H_v$ is a subgroup, so $I \in H_v$ (where $I$ is the identity matrix). You're trying to find $A$ such that $S_v = AH_v$; since $I \in H_v$, this implies $A \in S_v$. (And in fact, you can take any such $A$). Therefore, what you want to show is that given any $A \in S_v$, $B \in H_v$, then $AB \in S_v$.